# Создать шаблон хинта или балуна Яндекс карт через twig с функцией-фильтром

Tags: яндекс-карты, шаблоны, twig

Как можно преобразовать данные в темплейте ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass и потом пройтись циклом по ним. Не пойму почему не работают мои конструкции. В ЯК какой-то неполноценный twig?
Что я пробовал:

```
"<ul>{% for el in properties.geoObjects|filter %} <li>{{el}}</li> {% endfor %}</ul>"

"<ul>{% for el in {{properties.geoObjects|filter}} %} <li>{{el}}</li> {% endfor %}</ul>"

"{% set var = properties.geoObjects|filter %}"<ul>{% for el in var %}<li>{{el}}</li> {% endfor %}</ul>
```

Ничего из этого не работает. При чём просто:

```
"<div>{{properties.geoObjects|filter}}</div>"
```

так же как и отдельно:

```
"<ul>{% for el in properties.geoObject %} <li>{{el}}</li> {% endfor %}</ul>"
```

прекрасно работает и выводит всё как надо.